Extending the multiplication rule in probability theory
In basic probability theory I have seen two versions of the product rule. The first is
$$P(A \cap B) = P(B)P(A|B) \tag1$$
The derivation of that goes like this: -

Let there be N trials of an experiment, in which the event $A$ occurs $n_1$ times. Of these $n_1$ trials, event $B$ occurs $n_2$ times. It is clear that $n_2$ is the number of times that the joint event $A \cap  B$ occurs. That is,
$$P(A\cap B) = \lim_{N\to \infty} \frac{n_2}{N} = \lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{n_1}{N}\frac{n_2}{n_1} $$
We recognize that $\lim_{N\to\infty} \frac{n_1}{N} = P(A)$ and that $\lim_{N\to\infty}\frac{n_2}{n_1} = P(B|A)$. So we have from this
$$P(A \cap B) = P(A)P(B|A) $$
A similar argument can be made to show that (I'm not sure why this is true)
$$ P(A \cap B) = P(B)P(A|B)$$

The second version of the product rule is
$$P(A \cap B | C) = P(B|AC)P(A|C) \tag2$$
How does one derive $(2)$ from $(1)$? Also, is it possible to extend $(2)$ to

$P(A|B \cap C) $ and
$P(A \cap B | C \cap D)$?

Source for derivation of $(1)$: Modern and digital communication systems by Lathi.

This is far too much like homework. At least show us what convinces you as a proof of $(1)$ and explain where a similar proof of $(2)$ fails to convince you. Bear in mind that conditional probabilities satisfy all the axioms (and hence all the theorems) of unconditional probability and so a convincing proof of $(1)$ should be readily modifiable into a convincing proof of $(2)$.

@DilipSarwate I have updated the question showing a derivation of $(1)$.

Is it true that $B\cap A = A\cap B$? Why or why not? How about $P(B\cap A) = P(A\cap B)$? Can the argument that convincingly proved to you that $P(A\cap B)=P(A)P(B\mid A)$ be somehow modified to prove very convincingly to you that $P(B\cap A)=P(B)P(A\mid B)$ ?

@DilipSarwate Well, a conjunction is commutative, right? So $A \cap B = B \cap A$. Therefore, clearly we also have $P(A \cap B) = P(B \cap A)$. But I still don't see why this implies that $P(A)P(B|A) = P(B)P(A|B)$.

$P(A)P(B|A) = P(B)P(A|B)$ because both sides are equal to $P(A \cap B)$. You didn't complain when one side was shown equal to $P(A \cap B)$; why complain about the other side?

"But I still don't see why this implies that ()(|)=()(|)."  In the convincing proof that you firmly believe in, interchange $A$ and $B$ everywhere in the proof. Does this interchange result in a proof of the result that you are not sure about? How about including "Since we know that $P(B\cap A)=P(A\cap B)$, we can re-write what we have just proved, that $P(B \cap A)=P(B)P(A\mid B)$, as $P(A\cap B)=P(B)P(A\mid B)$, exactly as claimed."  Does this proof convince you? Why or why not?

@DilipSarwate In the derivation $n_1$ is the amount of times $A$ happens and $n_2$ is the amount of times out of the $n_1$ times that $B$ happens. If I do as you say and interchange $A$ and $B$ everywhere in the proof, then I also have to change $n_1$ to be the amount of times that $\mathbf{B}$ happens and $n_2$ the amount of times out of those $n_1$ times that $\mathbf{A}$ happens. Redoing the derivation with these changes will yield $P(A \cap B) = P(B)(A|B)$ but so what? I've changed the setting of the derivation from what it originally was and that is what confuses me.

@Carl Okay, whatever you say. You have a derivation of $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B\mid A)$ that is fully convincing to you. You also have a derivation that gives you $P(B\cap A) = P(B)P(A\mid B)$ that you derived for yourself, but have no faith in, even though your book says that it is a valid result, and it has been pointed out to you (and you have no beef with) that $P(B\cap a)=P(A\cap B)$.. Let's leave it that; a disagreement between you and everybody else as to the validity of one of these results.

@DilipSarwate I think I need to study the basics of probability theory more in depth before moving on to other things. I can feel I lack a basic understanding. I see you were an educator in probability theory in the past. What material (book) did you use in your teachings for this subject?


How does one derive (2) from (1)?

To derive this, first we can start by
$
P(A \cap B | C) = \frac{P((A \cap B) \cap C)}{P(C)} = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)}
$
Next, we simply apply the product rule to the event$
P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(B \cap C) P(A | B \cap C) $.
Then, it can express the conditional probability as $ P(A \cap B \cap C) = P(B \cap C) P(A | B \cap C)
$.
So,
$$
P(A \cap B | C) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(C)} = P(B | C) P(A | B \cap C) = P(A | C) P(B | A \cap C) = P(A | C) P(B | A C)
$$

is it possible to extend (2) to P(∩|∩)

Yes, start with the conditional probability,
$
P(A \cap B | C \cap D) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C \cap D)}{P(C \cap D)} = \frac{P(C \cap D) P(A | C \cap D) P(B | A \cap C \cap D)}{P(C \cap D)} = P(A | C \cap D) P(B | A \cap C \cap D) = P(A | CD) P(B | A C  D)
$
